# Input parameters in PUT resource handlers in Oracle APEX RESTful Services

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm building a REST API using [Oracle REST Data Services](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex-listener/documentation/listener-dev-guide-1979546.html) (Called RESTful Services in the APEX UI).

I can read `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` parameters in POST requests in PL/SQL handlers simply by using `:paramter_name`. However, they don't seem to work in PUT requests. [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21611_01/doc.11/e21058/rest_api.htm#AELIG7136) says that it should work with POST,PUT and DELETE operations. But I could only get it to work with POST.

Is this simply not supported for non-POST requests (and the documentation is misleading), or am I doing something wrong?

### Handler details

- RESTful Service Module: `hr/`
- URI Template: `test`
- Method: `PUT`
- Source Type: `PL/SQL`
- MIME Types Allowed: (empty)
- Requires Secure Access: `Yes`

Source:

```
begin
 :output := :input;
end;
```

Parameters:

```
Name    | Bind Variable Name    | Access Method | Source Type   | Parameter Type
--------|-----------------------|---------------|---------------|---------------
output  | output                | OUT           | Response Body | String
```

### Example request

The request I tried is:

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'input=test' https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/redacted/hr/test
```

I simply get an empty response.

However, if I change the handler to Method: `POST`, and try the following request:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'input=test' https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/redacted/hr/test
```

I get the correct response which is:

```
{"output":"test"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently ORDS only supports json PUT parameters.  You can reference 1st level directly. If you need nested json,  then you need to parse :body (convert to clob) and use APEX_JSON (Apex 5.0)

Example:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT -d '{"test1":"xyz","test2":"123", "test3":"asd"}' https://test.example.com/ords/slrv/oliTest/data

{"test1":"xyz", "test2":"123", "test3":"asd","test4":""}
```

Backend code (type plsql)

```
begin
   owa_util.status_line (200, '', false);
   owa_util.mime_header ('application/json', true);
   htp.prn ('
{"test1":"' || :test1 || '", "test2":"' || :test2 || '", "test3":"' || :test3 || '","test4":"' || :test4 || '"}
');
end;
```